# Will making my site secure (https) affect my google ranking?

Tags: security, http, redirect, https, ssl-certificate

I am managing a website (www.faa.net.au) which is currently running as a standard http:// website.

I am now looking at capturing some information that needs to be confidential. In order to do this, I am looking at purchasing an SSL Certificate for this particular domain.

I have 2 questions really:

1. Will my Rankings be effected at all?
2. Will I need to set up 301 redirects if there are links that are referring to http:// instead of https://?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gong HTTPS will **not** negatively affect your page rankings.  And yes, you should set up a 301 redirect unless this is a temporary change.

In a nutshell, the search engine bots connect to the pages as normal, so it doesn't matter if it's using SSL/TLS or not.  The 301 will pretty much update the bots with the current information.

Answer (score 1):

Going https will actually positivly affect your site's SEO as Google has now introduced it as a ranking factor. http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal.html